# Returning a list of generic entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

```
public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
   List<Customer> listOfCustomers = db.Customer.ToList();
   return listOfCustomers;
}
```

I have a database with three tables (entities): Customer, Event and Venue. As you can see I am returning a list containing Customers but I would like to know if there is a way that I can return the entities in the list as something more generic. This would allow me not to be forced having separate get methods for all entities.

I have searched the web but found nothing that was applicable when using lamdba syntax.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: public List<T> GetList<T>() ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the job, just use the [`Set<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) property of your context:

```
public List<T> GetEntities<T>() where T : class
{
    return db.Set<T>().ToList();
}
```

However, you probably want to keep this function returning an `IQueryable<T>` rather than a `List<T>` so you can continue to benefit from deferred execution. So the method becomes:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetEntities<T>() where T : class
{
    return db.Set<T>();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
List<Customer> listOfCustomers = GetEntities<Customer>();
```

Or with the `IQueryable<T>` version:

```
IQueryable<Customer> listOfCustomers = GetEntities<Customer>();
```

Which you can now query properly:

```
IQueryable<Customer> allCustomers = listOfCustomers;
List<Customer> onlyBobs = allCustomers
    .Where(c => c.Name = "Bob")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You posted answer in the same time as i posted a comment ;) Upvoted!

Comment: Yes, this should work! However, I am not sure I understand as I get "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter 'TEntity'. What have I overlooked?

Comment: @Ohlafl Made an edit that should fix that. Typed that all out from memory so forgot about [generic type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)!

Comment: @Ohlafl Not sure I actually saved any lives here, but you're welcome nonetheless!

Comment: @DavidG I have another quick question: Is there any way to make the returned items in the list generic aswell? So that it would be possible to use in a delegate where the return might be List<Customer> or List<Event> ?

Comment: @Ohlafl Not sure what you mean, you will have to give me some example code (which means you need to ask another question!) :)